# `ModuleNotFoundError` during "absolute" path import

Tags: python, python-3.x

[ I understand questions like these are many and I have rtfm-ed, stackoverflow-ed, google-d widely, but there's something basic that seems to elude the troubleshooting.
So I am giving up on some basic Python troubleshooting and asking for help here
]

The project structure is as foll:

```
(venv) jcn@host:~/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks$ tree
.
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── logs
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── common_mod_00_immutable_cnstnts.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── common_mod_00_immutable_cnstnts.py
│   │   ├── common_mod_01_parse_resultsxml.py
│   │   ├── common_mod_02_logging_tailing.py
│   │   └── common_mod_03_setup_swingbench_paramiko.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── main_absl_refactored.py
│   ├── main_args.py
│   ├── scenarios
│   │   └── scenario_mod_01_instancedown.py
│   └── user_inputs.json
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_args.py
```

I am trying to import `for_gob_unittests_mocks/src/main_absl_refactored.py` using Python's **absolute import**...

Contents are:

main_absl_refactored.py:

```
def parse_cmd_line_flags() -> dict:
    return {'a': 1}
```

test_args.py:

```
from for_gob_unittests_mocks.src.main_absl_refactored import parse_cmd_line_flags
```

Error:

```
(venv) jcn@host:~/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks$ python tests/test_args.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests/test_args.py", line 3, in <module>
    from for_gob_unittests_mocks.src.main_absl_refactored import parse_cmd_line_flags
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'for_gob_unittests_mocks'
```

I have tried adding the directory `/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks` into Python's `sys.path`...it didn't help.

Modified content of `test_args.py` to designate the `for_gob_unittests_mocks` directory as a source directory:

```
import sys, pathlib

print(sys.path)

curr_dir_obj = pathlib.Path(__file__ ).absolute()
sys.path.append(str(curr_dir_obj.parent.parent))

print(sys.path)

from for_gob_unittests_mocks.src.main_absl_refactored import parse_cmd_line_flags
```

Same error, but with some info on `sys.path`:

```
(venv) jcn@host:~/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks$ python tests/test_args.py 
['/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
['/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests/test_args.py", line 12, in <module>
    from for_gob_unittests_mocks.src.main_absl_refactored import parse_cmd_line_flags
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'for_gob_unittests_mocks'
```

Comment: Did you find existing Stack Overflow answers? If so, what did you find, what specifically did you try in order to implement that answer, and what happened when you tried it? If you believe your solution was different, what is your take - did you *misunderstand* the answer, or is there something *wrong* in it? This question as it stands is not really appropriate as a separate question, because of how it was resolved (effectively a typo), but you can help us improve existing answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree that this was a silly miss on my part with regards to editing the sys.path and apologies for posting it as a question, but I had to as I was in the trenches for hours and couldn't get through this...

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue.

###### Issue:

The issue was that I was trying to add `for_gob_unittests_mocks` into the `sys.path` list.

###### Solution:

I should have added the parent of `for_gob_unittests_mocks` into the `sys.path` list. Like so:

test_args.py:

```
import sys, pathlib

print(sys.path)

curr_dir_obj = pathlib.Path(__file__ ).absolute()
sys.path.append(str(curr_dir_obj.parent.parent.parent)) #  corresponds to >>> `/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/`

print(sys.path)

from for_gob_unittests_mocks.src.main_absl_refactored import parse_cmd_line_flags
```

O/P:

```
(venv) jcn@host:~/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks$ python tests/test_args.py 
['/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
['/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/for_gob_unittests_mocks/tests', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/home/jcn/PycharmProjects/hadr']
```